# error when trying to check if user docs existed

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-dependencies

Error: A value of type 'GoogleSignInAccount? Function()' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'GoogleSignInAccount'. lib/services/authentication_service.dart:33 - 'GoogleSignInAccount' is from 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart' ('../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_sign_in-5.3.3/lib/google_sign_in.dart'). package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:1       GoogleSignInAccount  googleSignInAccount = googleSignin.currentUser!; site:stackoverflow.com

```
  Future<bool?> checkUserInFirestore(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignin googleSignin=GoogleSignin();
      GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount = googleSignin.currentUser;
      if (googleSignInAccount == null) return null;
      final doc = await users.doc(googleSignInAccount.id).get();
      bool isExist = doc.exists;
      return isExist;
    } catch (error) {
      displayMessage(error.toString(), context);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update this line of code,

```
final doc = await users.doc(googleSignInAccount!.id).get();
```

Comment: still gives me the same error